# Deposit of bitcoin

Tags: bitcoind

Could you tell me why i didn't get all my money (from 0,66 BTC i got only 0,26 BTC) on my Cryptopia account. You can see 5 transactions from bitins (each 0,13 BTC)

```
35290 - 81b5d7f84a230dc9350572e76853b6bdc9e48989ec26b7787b91fcf53181574a
35291 - 81b5d7f84a230dc9350572e76853b6bdc9e48989ec26b7787b91fcf53181574a
35294 - 7946f99c156212334a562aa28766e08c54e96a16c78341574ac6e62f8e82ea10
35295 - 7946f99c156212334a562aa28766e08c54e96a16c78341574ac6e62f8e82ea10
35296 - 7946f99c156212334a562aa28766e08c54e96a16c78341574ac6e62f8e82ea10
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the transactions on the blockchain explorer and both have been added to blocks and have been confirmed more than enough times. The bitins site does have a comment on their redeem a voucher page which states that they are having problems with their transactions not being processed quickly on the bitcoin network. It does look like they are experiencing problems but not sure if that would explain why you are not seeing your full transaction amounts.